# DTO to entity mapping when entity has many to one relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I'm trying to map business object into entity but got stuck and have no idea how to resolve this.

The problem is when I try to map these attributes from DTO which are attributes of many-to-one relationship with another table.

Here is how my `Entity` looks like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_car")
public class Car extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "pkIdCar")
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(45)")
private String brand;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer productionYear;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Float engineCapacity;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Float power;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Integer distance;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fkIdType")
private CarType carType;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fkIdColor")
private Color color;
... }
```

And here is `DTO`:

```
public class CarDto {

private Long id;

private String brand;

private Integer productionYear;

private Float engineCapacity;

private Float power;

private Integer distance;

private CarTypes carType;

private ColorTypes color;
... }
```

`CarTypes` and `ColorTypes` are enums which have assigned number corresponding to their primary key in database. For example `CarTypes` is:

```
REGULAR_TWO_DOOR(1),
REGULAR_FOUR_DOOR(2),
STATION_WAGON(3),
MINIVAN(4),
SPORT(5),
LUXURY(6);
```

And here is the mapper i managed to write. How can I assign proper `CarType` (that's entity) to `carEntity` basing on `CarType` primary key?

```
public class CarMapper {

...
public static Car carDtoToCar(CarDto carDto, Car carEntity) {

    if(carEntity == null) {
        carEntity = new Car();
    }

    carEntity.setBrand(carDto.getBrand());
    carEntity.setProductionYear(carDto.getProductionYear());
    carEntity.setEngineCapacity(carDto.getEngineCapacity());
    carEntity.setPower(carDto.getPower());
    carEntity.setDistance(carDto.getDistance());

    Long carTypeId = Long.valueOf(carDto.getCarType().getNumber());
    Long carColorId = Long.valueOf(carDto.getColor().getNumber());

    /* ? */

    return carEntity;
}
}
```

`CarType` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_car_type")
public class CarType extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "pkIdType")
private Long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition="VARCHAR(45)")
private CarTypes type;
... }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get the `CarType` entity based on the Cartype Id. For example:
  `CarType carType = entityManager.find(CarType.class, carTypeId);`
- And then set this `carType` in `CarEntity` as
  `carEntity.setCarType(carType);`

Comment: is there a shorter way to achieve this ?